# Projecting 2D Generated Mesh onto 3D Uniform grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics, 3d

I have the following patterned mesh in 2D[image]

I have a curved grid of 3D Uniform points
[image]

My trial:

1. The patterned mesh is from UV coordinates 0 to 1 mapped to those values
2. using cubic interpolation, I'm getting a point on the Curved Mesh
3. Using the indices of the patterned mesh I get a result mesh with the points that are interpolated from #2

The problem is I get a flattened curved mesh as shown it doesn't have the required depth due to using 2D Coordinates in the patterned mesh:
[image]

While the result mesh should look like this:

[image]

I'm using the following code to do the purpose:

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> voronoi_project_to_3D(std::vector<glm::vec3> &voronoi_pnts)
{
    int i, iu, iv;
    float u, v;
    vec2 p0{}, p1{};
    vec3 p;
    vec3 c[4 * 4];
    std::vector < glm::vec3> points_3d;
    // compute BBOX of 2D voronoi
    for (i = 0; i < voronoi_pnts.size(); i++)
    {
        p = voronoi_pnts[i];
        if (!i) { p0 = p; p1 = p; }
        if (p0.x > p.x) p0.x = p.x;
        if (p1.x < p.x) p1.x = p.x;
        if (p0.y > p.y) p0.y = p.y;
        if (p1.y < p.y) p1.y = p.y;
    }
    // convert ot 3D
    p1.x = float(mesh_nu-35) / (p1.x - p0.x);
    p1.y = float(mesh_nv-35) / (p1.y - p0.y);
    for (i = 0; i < voronoi_pnts.size(); i++)
    {
        p = voronoi_pnts[i];
        u = (p.x - p0.x) * p1.x;
        v = (p.y - p0.y) * p1.y;
        iu = floor(u); u -= iu;
        iv = floor(v); v -= iv;
        cubic_surface_set_it4(c,
            mesh_pnt + iu + ((iv + 0) * mesh_nu),
            mesh_pnt + iu + ((iv + 1) * mesh_nu),
            mesh_pnt + iu + ((iv + 2) * mesh_nu),
            mesh_pnt + iu + ((iv + 3) * mesh_nu));
        points_3d.push_back(cubic_surface_get_it4(c, u, v));
    }
    return points_3d;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to copy the `mesh_pnt` sample (declaration along with the `nu,nv` constants) so only those of us who already have it know whats going on. Also you use `cubic_surface_???` functions but not copy nor describe them so other users without context can not help. I do not see any problem with the function (as its just port of mine which does work) so maybe the problem is elsewhere ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the scaling from BBOX to `u,v` and `iu,iv` ... as the target is piecewise cubic surface patch of resolution `mesh_nu,mesh_nv` control points we need to select 4x4 control points starting with index `0,0` and ending with `mesh_nu-3,mesh_nv-3` as cubic surface need 4 points per patch and axis so the code should be:

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> voronoi_project_to_3D(std::vector<glm::vec3> &voronoi_pnts)
{
    int i, iu, iv;
    float u, v;
    vec2 p0{}, p1{};
    vec3 p;
    vec3 c[4 * 4];
    std::vector < glm::vec3> points_3d;
    // compute BBOX of 2D voronoi
    for (i = 0; i < voronoi_pnts.size(); i++)
    {
        p = voronoi_pnts[i];
        if (!i) { p0 = p; p1 = p; }
        if (p0.x > p.x) p0.x = p.x;
        if (p1.x < p.x) p1.x = p.x;
        if (p0.y > p.y) p0.y = p.y;
        if (p1.y < p.y) p1.y = p.y;
    }
    // convert ot 3D
    p1.x = float(mesh_nu-3) / (p1.x - p0.x);
    p1.y = float(mesh_nv-3) / (p1.y - p0.y);
    for (i = 0; i < voronoi_pnts.size(); i++)
    {
        p = voronoi_pnts[i];
        u = (p.x - p0.x) * p1.x;
        v = (p.y - p0.y) * p1.y;
        iu = floor(u); u -= iu;
        iv = floor(v); v -= iv;
        cubic_surface_set_it4(c,
            mesh_pnt + iu + ((iv + 0) * mesh_nu),
            mesh_pnt + iu + ((iv + 1) * mesh_nu),
            mesh_pnt + iu + ((iv + 2) * mesh_nu),
            mesh_pnt + iu + ((iv + 3) * mesh_nu));
        points_3d.push_back(cubic_surface_get_it4(c, u, v));
    }
    return points_3d;
}
```

Note I changed the `-35` to `-3` in order to work properly the constants `mesh_nu,mesh_nv` must match the cubic surface control points `mesh_pnt` topology...

For those of you that do not have context to this QA here full VCL/OpenGL source (BDS2006 C++ Builder) and win32 binary:

- [Win32 OpenGL/VCL C++ example for cubic surface and 2D mesh projection onto it](https://ulozto.net/tamhle/82u8i6pwxG8K#!ZJL5MQR2AJLmAJRkZ2RmAJRjMzZ4A0f4E3uTL2gQYHgRomZkMN==)

The example also contains my `GLSL_math.h` template and newest version of `gl_simple.h` (supporting geometry shaders) which I often use for SO code examples in my answers...
Here also related chat (containing all the info about the stuff behind it):

- [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249677/3d-graphics)

Comment: Hello Spektre, What IF The mesh that I want to project onto is a 3D Mesh with UV Mapping, how would that differ of what we are doing ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh no difference at all its still 2D points ...

Comment: Can you come to the chat please ?